# How do I find range using AM-GM inequality

Tags: functions, inequality

I have been given a function, $$ f(x)= x^2+ \dfrac{9}{x^2} $$ and I been told to find the range of this function using AM-GM inequality only.

I was able to calculate minimum value of $f(x)$ which is $6$

$$ x^2 + \dfrac{9}{x^2} ≥ 6$$

and by setting $x^2 = \dfrac{9}{x^2}$ I get min value as $6$

But how do I calculate maximum value for the range?

Comment: Think about what happens for large $x$ values

Comment: or when $x$ is close to $0$

Answer (score 2):

Because of $x^2$ and the positivity of $\frac9{x^2}$, the function has no maximum value (it is unbounded above as $x\to\infty$ or $x\to0$).

Comment: How do I know at what values of $x$ I need to check?

Comment: @William Formally: show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^2+9/x^2)=+\infty$. This should be easy to do by considering that $x^2$ also goes to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: what is the motivation for showing $f(x) \to + \infty$. I mean it could be anything, right?

Comment: @William It can be _as large as you like_. That is the point. There is no finite maximum value.

Comment: So you mean I can directly include $\infty$ in range in every AM-GM range problem?

Comment: @William If it comes up, yes.

Answer (score 1):

No maximum exists there since $$f(x)>x^2$$which means that $f(x)$ can be arbitrarily large. Here is a sketch[image]

Comment: I don't think I'm gonna get a graph calculator in exam :/

Comment: Then i also wrote the analytic reason